# Android Studio Kotlin: Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState()

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, webview

I'm trying to make an app for my college using webview and our college website has files to download so I added a way to download `.pdf` files to the user's device but the issue is that i get some cannot create snapshot error whenever i try to run the app or build the app.

Here are my files:

`mainActivity.kt`:

```
package com.github.spaciouscoder78.courseweb

import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.webkit.*
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    //creating a webview object
    private lateinit var webView:WebView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //looking for the webview id from android main
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        //transferring the control to webviewclient
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        //loading the url
        webView.loadUrl("https://kitsw.rlabs.co.in/")
        //enabling javascript so it actually works
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
        //adding zoom support
        webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)

        webView.setDownloadListener(DownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength ->
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(url)
            )
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED) //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                "Download.pdf"
            )
            val dm = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            dm.enqueue(request)
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Downloading File",  //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        })

    }
    override fun onBackPressed(){
        //allowing user to go back
        if(webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack()
        else
            super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />        <!-- for your file, say a pdf to work -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/kitswlogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/kitswlogo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Courseweb"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.github.spaciouscoder78.courseweb"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.github.spaciouscoder78.courseweb"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.webkit:webkit:1.8.0");
}
```

I don't understand how to fix this

**Edit:**
Forgot to include the error

````
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.deprecation.DocumentedFailure$DocumentedExceptionWithCause: Cannot access output property 'incrementalFolder' of task ':app:packageDebug'. Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/incremental_build.html#disable-state-tracking for more details.
    at org.gradle.internal.deprecation.DocumentedFailure$Builder.build(DocumentedFailure.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.decorateSnapshottingException(TaskExecution.java:380)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.visitOutputs(TaskExecution.java:348)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultOutputSnapshotter.snapshotOutputs(DefaultOutputSnapshotter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionState$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\aryan\OneDrive\Documents\Github\courseweb-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\javaResources0: not a regular file
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$PathVisitor.snapshotFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:420)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$PathVisitor.visitResolvedFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:393)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$PathVisitor.doVisitFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:353)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotterStatistics$CollectingFileVisitor.visitFile(DirectorySnapshotterStatistics.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotterStatistics$CollectingFileVisitor.visitFile(DirectorySnapshotterStatistics.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter.snapshot(DirectorySnapshotter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$snapshot$7(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.AbstractVirtualFileSystem.store(AbstractVirtualFileSystem.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readLocation$8(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readSnapshotFromLocation$9(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:189)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readSnapshotFromLocation$10(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:186)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readSnapshotFromLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:186)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readSnapshotFromLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.read(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$SnapshottingVisitor.visitCollection(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.visitContents(AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:366)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.visitSingleFile(UnpackingVisitor.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileCollectionFactory$ResolvingFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultFileCollectionFactory.java:254)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:366)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultOutputSnapshotter$1.visitOutputProperty(DefaultOutputSnapshotter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.visitOutputs(TaskExecution.java:342)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\aryan\OneDrive\Documents\Github\courseweb-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageDebug\tmp\debug\zip-cache\javaResources0: not a regular file
    ... 92 more
    ```
````